# Is it possible to put an attribute's value into an array?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get the value of the attribute from the input xml file and have the same value of the attribute be divided into different attribute in the target.For example the input xml file has the following element

```
     <Heading style="-uslm-lc:I665505" class="centered fontsize18">Heading
      </Heading>
```

'''This is the targeted xml file the format and values are from style attribute style="-uslm-lc:I665505"

```
  <para format="6655" loc="05">Heading</para>
```

I have to get format="6655" and loc="05" in the para element in the target xml. How do I do it?

Comment: There is a feature since XSLT 1.0 known as [Named Attribute Sets](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-sets)

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="Heading">
    <para format="{substring(@style, 11, 4)}" loc="{substring(@style, 15, 2)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

will return the expected result for the given example - see demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiS

It's not possible to say whether this will work for all your cases, because all we have is a single example and no rules. And there is no "array" here.